# Select data without SubQuery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two tables with name Test and testHistory in TestHistory has the FK Relationship with Test.

[image: Test table data]

[image: testHistory table data]

Now I want to select the Top 1 Inserted data from table TestHistory with Test Table records.

My desired Output would be:

[image]

Or It is not necessary that my TestHistory table has the records related to TestId , then my output would be:

[image]

I have achieve this with sub query like:

```
Select Id,(select top(1) price from TestHistory HT Where T.Id=HT.TestId order by HT.Id desc) As Price 

From Test T
```

But I don't want to use the sub query for that.
I want to do select data without sub query .

Please suggest me how I can do that without Sub query, what will be the best alternate way to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to do this would be to use `row_number()` to get the result but you will still have a subquery. This will not be a correlated subquery though:

```
select id, price, testhistoryid
from
(
  select t.id,
    h.price,
    h.id testhistoryid,
    row_number() over(partition by t.id order by h.id desc) rn
  from test t
  inner join testhistory h
    on t.id = h.testid
) src
where rn = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/19be3/4).

If you want to return the `test` rows if they do not exist in the history table, then you will use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of an `INNER JOIN`:

```
select id, price, testhistoryid
from
(
  select t.id,
    h.price,
    h.id testhistoryid,
    row_number() over(partition by t.id order by h.id desc) rn
  from test t
  left join testhistory h
    on t.id = h.testid
) src
where rn = 1;
```

See [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f989c/1)

Comment: Is this query better performance wise in comparison simple subjqery(like I have wrote)?

Comment: @bluefeet, I would normally put only the `testhistory` table inside the subquery and do the join to `test` outside (such as in my answer). Do you find that the optimizer treats your in-the-subquery way the same as I am suggesting?

Comment: @ErikE it's just habit to place them both in the subquery and I don't have the ability to test it right now to see what performs better

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but there's no real way to do this without some kind of subquery. The query you've written is fine. In my opinion, the best syntax to accomplish what you're looking for is this:

```
SELECT
   T.ID,
   HT.*
FROM
   dbo.Test T
   OUTER APPLY (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM dbo.TestHistory HT
      WHERE T.ID = HT.TestID
      ORDER BY HT.ID DESC
   ) HT
;
```

[Try this out yourself in a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae068/3).

If you want to restrict it so only those `Test` rows with a matching `TestHistory` row are shown then use `CROSS APPLY` instead of `OUTER APPLY`.

Also, such a query as this is possible and maybe easier to understand, but will most likely not perform as well, plus it requires there to be at least one `TestHistory` row for each `Test` row.

```
SELECT
   T.ID,
   HT.*
FROM
   dbo.Test T
   INNER JOIN dbo.TestHistory HT
      ON T.ID = HT.TestID
WHERE
   HT.ID = (
      SELECT Max(HT2.ID)
      FROM dbo.TestHistory HT2
      WHERE T.ID = HT2.TestID
   )
;
```

You can also use a `Row_Number()` solution, though I tend to lean away from that since it often doesn't perform as well as `CROSS APPLY` with `TOP`, when that is available.

```
SELECT
   T.ID,
   HT.TestID,
   HT.Price
FROM
   dbo.Test T
   LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT
         Selector = Row_Number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY HT.TestID ORDER BY HT.ID DESC
         ),
         *
      FROM dbo.TestHistory HT
   ) HT
      ON T.ID = HT.TestID
      AND HT.Selector = 1
;
```

[Try this out yourself in a SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ae068/3).

The only way to find out whether the `TOP 1` or the `Row_Number()` solution performs better is to try each one in your database with lots of data that is properly representative. If you have very few history entries and very many main entries, you **might** get better results with `Row_Number()`. But if you have many history entries for each main entry, the `TOP` method will probably perform best.

The indexes on your tables can also make an enormous difference. Make sure that you've got sensible indexes that allow the proper table accesses (for example, the clustered index on table `TestHistory` should be on `TestID, ID`, even if the PK is on `ID`'). The indexes may not matter so much if you are querying the entire table every time, but the moment you have a condition restricting the set of `Test` rows, the indexes will become very important.